# What does thirteen numbers refer to in 'Parashambhu Mahimna' stavam by Durvasa?

Tags: shiva, durvasa

Recently I came to know about the existence of the following stavam named '**[Parashambhu Mahimna](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/parashambhUmahimnastavadUrvAsa.html?lang=sa)**' written by Durvasa. I want to know the importance of the numbers and what they refer to in the stavam. So, I presented and highlighted only certain places where numbers are present.

> शिवाभ्यां नमः
>
> परशम्भुमहिम्नस्तवः
>
> अनुक्रमणिका श्लोकसङ्ख्यासहितं
>
> १   उपोद्घातप्रकरणं **प्रथमम्** ॥ १॥  १८
>
> २   पराशक्तिस्कन्धरश्मिप्रकरणं **द्वितीयम्** ॥ २॥    ७
>
> ३   इच्छाशक्तिस्कन्धरश्मि प्रकरणं **तृतीयम्** ॥ ३॥    ८
>
> ४   ज्ञानशक्तिस्कन्धरश्मिप्रकरणं **चतुर्थम्** ॥ ४॥    ६
>
> ५   क्रियाशक्तिस्कन्धरश्मिप्रकरणं **पञ्चमम्** ॥ ५॥  १२
>
> ६   कुण्डलिनीशक्तिस्कन्धरश्मिप्रकरणं **षष्ठम्** ॥ ६॥   ६
>
> ७   मातृकाशक्तिस्कन्धरश्मिप्रकरणं **सप्तमम्** ॥ ७॥ १०
>
> ८   षडन्वयरश्मिविवेकस्कन्धप्रकरण**मष्टमम्** ॥ ८॥   ५
>
> ९   पावकध्यानयोगप्रकरणं **नवमम्** ॥ ९॥   ११
>
> १० महाविभूतिप्रकरणं **दशमम्** ॥ १०॥   १७
>
> ११ अन्तर्यागोपाचारपरामर्शप्रकरण**मेकादशम्** ॥ ११॥   ८
>
> १२ शान्तिप्रकरणं **द्वादशम्** ॥ १२॥    १२
>
> १३ उपसंहारप्रकरणं **त्रयोदशम्** ॥ १३॥   २१
>
> पूर्णस्तवश्लोकसङ्ख्या १४१
>
> १. **प्रथमं** प्रकरणं उपोद्घात ...........
>
> २. **द्वितीयं** प्रकरणं पराशक्तिस्कन्धरश्मि .........
>
> ३. **तृतीयं** प्रकरणं इच्छाशक्तिस्कन्धरश्मि .........
>
> ४. **चतुर्थ** प्रकरणं ज्ञानशक्तिस्कन्धरश्मि ..........
>
> ५. **पञ्चम** प्रकरणं क्रियाशक्तिस्कन्धरश्मि .........
>
> ६. **षष्ठं** प्रकरणं कुण्डलिनीशक्तिस्कन्धरश्मि ........
>
> ७. **सप्तमं** प्रकरणं मातृकाशक्तिस्कन्धरश्मि .........
>
> ८. **अष्टमं** प्रकरणं षडन्वयरश्मिविवेकस्कन्ध ........
>
> ९. **नवमं** प्रकरणं पावकध्यानयोग ..........
>
> १०. **दशमं** प्रकरणं महाविभूति ...........
>
> ११. **एकादशं** प्रकरणं अन्तर्यागोपाचारपरामर्श ......
>
> १२. **द्वादशं** प्रकरणं शान्ति .........
>
> १३. **त्रयोदशं** प्रकरणं उपसंहार ........

If you see the structure of the stavam, it has thirteen sub-parts. Each subpart seems to be explaining something. What is that? Are they thirteen aspects of lord Siva? Or some other? Please answer in a high-level overview rather than in detail.

---

**Note**: I am not asking for translation or meaning for the entire stavam. I am interested in knowing only the high-level details of the thirteen classes mentioned in the stavam. I am asking this question because I found no sources containing its meaning online. But you can find [here](https://stotram.co.in/parashambhu-mahimna-stavam/), the stavam in many languages.